# Security concerns using Spring as backend for mobile app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, server, backend

Me and a team built a small "meet people" app last semester that used Spring linked to a MySQL database as the backend. I am working on my own app now and I'm worried about security because all of our user information was sent over HTTPS GET requests to the server. It seems weird to me that we were able to hop on google chrome, type in xxx.xxxxx.xx:xxx/user/2 and get back a JSON with all of a specific users information. If anyone knew our url/port, they would be able to access this information themselves.

I'm sure this is a basic question, but what steps do I need to take to create a Spring backend that isn't as easy to access? I'm basically a total beginner in this, but I did write the service in Spring last semester so I know the basics.

Comment: Despite searching before asking this question, now that I have asked I've been looking at the related posts.. Is token authentication what I need to be thinking about?

Comment: If you've just put spring security on the classpath the information wouldn't be publicly available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) which is a very good project and easy to integrate.

There are many types of security features it provides :

1. [Basic Spring Security](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)
2. [Role Based Spring Security](http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration)

[baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/security-spring) and [howtodoinjava](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-security-tutorial/) has a very good series on it.

---

You can also use [jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) which is also a good way to secure the APIs.

Comment: Thank you!! Hadn't seen this during our last build.

Comment: Happy to help :)